# TypeError: Failed to fetch

Tags: javascript, node.js, fetch

I have a index.pug file, that is render by GET, and Post that returns data into json.

```
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('index', { title: 'agrotaxi' });
});

router.post('/', async function(req, res) {
......
res.json(info);
});
```

The problem is that when you try to fetch the result i've got:

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to fetch
```

my fetch function:

```
   document.getElementById('go').addEventListener('click',getdata);

   function getdata() {

       let start = document.getElementById('start').value;
       let end = document.getElementById('end').value;

       let options = {
           "start": start,
           "end": end
       };
       fetch('http://localhost:3000', {
           method: 'post',
           headers: {
               "Content-type": "application/json; charset=UTF-8"
           },
           body:JSON.stringify(options)
       })
       .then(function(res){
           return res.json(); //error here
       })
       .then(function(data){
           console.log(data);
       });
   }
```

Don't understand what i do wrong.
[the pic of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FYQPc.png)

Answer (score 6):

Maybe the problem the fetch fails for some reason and you are not capturing the error, so, try adding the catch method in this way:

```
fetch('http://localhost:3000', {
  method: 'post',
  headers: {
    "Content-type": "application/json; charset=UTF-8"
  },
  body:JSON.stringify(options)
}).then(function(res){
  return res.json(); //error here
}).then(function(data){
  console.log(data);
}).catch((error) => {
  console.log(error);
});
```

Comment: Added that, by also have the same problem.

Comment: Did you enable CORS on NodeJS to allow your frontend webpage domain?